# Запрос зависимый минимум от двух, или больше совпадений

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо составить запрос который ищет возможные совпадения, но надо что бы он срого учитывал 2 условия.

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE
ID='$id1' or tower='$tower1' or reg='$adress1' or floor='$floor1' or area='$area1' or undonds='$undonds1' or price='$price1' and rentorsale='1'and salebis='1'
```

В данном примере, rentorsale и salebis должны учитываться в первую очередь, а потом, если совпадают, учитываться и другие.
Сейчас проблема в том что учитывается лишь rentorsale, а salebis игнорируется.

Comment: напишите ему явно (rentorsale='1' and salebis='1')  and (a or b)

Comment: *rentorsale и salebis должны учитываться в первую очередь* В запросе нет никаких очередей. Условие или проверяется, или нет. Если условие проверяется, но не выполняется, запись не выводится, иначе - выводится. Всё.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  (
    select
      * 
    from
      objects 
    where
      rentorsale = '2' 
      and salebis = '1' 
      and activity = '1' 
  )
  AS results 
where
  ID = '$id1' 
  or tower = '$tower1' 
  or reg = '$adress1' 
  or floor = '$floor1' 
  or area = '$area1' 
  or undonds = '$undonds1' 
  or price = '$price1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM objects 
WHERE (ID        ='$id1'     )
    + (tower     ='$tower1'  )
    + (reg       ='$adress1' )
    + (floor     ='$floor1'  )
    + (area      ='$area1'   )
    + (undonds   ='$undonds1')
    + (price     ='$price1'  )
    + (rentorsale='1'        )
    + (salebis   ='1'        )  >= 2
```